# Is state returned in an RPC query with a context slot just BEFORE or AFTER the slot has been proessed?

Tags: rpc

For example, if I call `getAccountInfoWithContext`, it'll return me the account state + the context with a slot number.

Is the account state just BEFORE the slot is processed (ie before all txs in the slot have been simulated) or AFTER all the txs in that slot?

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark this as answered. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**slot**:
The period of time for which each leader ingests transactions and produces a block.

**block**: A contiguous set of entries on the ledger covered by a vote. A leader produces at most one block per slot.

from https://docs.solana.com/terminology

The returned account state is the state in that slot number, it might be different in the previous slot or the next slot (in case some changes happened)

So to answer your question, the account state is after that slot has been processed.